# Не отображает данные RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, recyclerview.adapter

В адаптер не приходят данные, хотя в логах они есть
[image: Лог данных]

Активити:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeView{

@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private HomePresenter presenter;
private RecyclerViewHomeAdapter homeAdapter;
private List<ShopData.Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    presenter = new HomePresenter(this);
    presenter.getData();
    homeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(items, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


}

@Override
public void setData(List<ShopData.Item> itemList) {
    items.addAll(itemList);
    homeAdapter.setItemList(items);
}

@Override
public void onErrorLoading(String message) {
    Utils.showDialogMessage(this, "Tittle", message);
}}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class RecyclerViewHomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHomeAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private List<ShopData.Item> itemList;
private Context context;

public RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(List<ShopData.Item> itemList, Context context) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setItemList(List<ShopData.Item> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ShopData.Item item = itemList.get(position);
    holder.bind(item);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.tv_title)
    TextView item_title;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_category)
    TextView item_category;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_price)
    TextView item_price;
    @BindView(R.id.card_item)
    CardView cardView_item;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    void bind(ShopData.Item type) {
        item_title.setText(type.getName());
        item_category.setText(type.getType());
        item_price.setText(String.valueOf(type.getPrice()));
    }
}}
```

Презентер:

```
public class HomePresenter {

private HomeView view;

public HomePresenter(HomeView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

void getData() {
    Call<ShopData> shopDataCall = Utils.getApi().getData();
    shopDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<ShopData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ShopData> call, Response<ShopData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                view.setData(response.body().getData());
            }
            else {
                view.onErrorLoading(response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ShopData> call, Throwable t) {
            view.onErrorLoading(t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}}
```

Модель:

```
public class ShopData {

@Json(name = "data")
private List<Item> data = null;

public List<Item> getData() {
    return data;
}

public static class Item {

    @Json(name = "id")
    public Integer id;
    @Json(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Json(name = "price")
    private Double price;
    @Json(name = "bar_code")
    private String barCode;
    @Json(name = "book_category")
    public BookCategory bookCategory;
    @Json(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Json(name = "properties")
    public List<Property> properties = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public static class Property {

        @Json(name = "id")
        public Integer id;
        @Json(name = "name")
        public String name;
        @Json(name = "value")
        public Integer value;

    }

    public static class BookCategory {

        @Json(name = "id")
        public Integer id;
        @Json(name = "name")
        public String name;

    }
}}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "omnis",
    "price": 55393.06,
    "bar_code": "642345",
    "book_category": null,
    "type": "cd",
    "properties": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "cd_type",
    "value": "cd"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "cd_content",
    "value": "видео"
    }
    ]
    }
    ],
    "links": {},
    "meta": {}
    }
```

Comment: А что у вас в презентере? То, что у вас где-то что-то в логи пишется не означает, что метод View вызван. Наверное, в этом и дело.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в начале  метода `setItemList` строку `this.itemList.clear()`

Comment: Добавил презентер.

Comment: То есть у вас не вызывается ни `setData()`, ни `onErrorLoading()` и приложение не падает и никаких ошибок в логах тоже нет?

Comment: Начните с отслеживания, и желательно с конца (можно через дебаггер если умеете) я делал всегда так: в самый конец тыкал логи: в методе onBindView(...) {Log.e("Ept", "Item = " + item.id;)}; Но я более чем уверен что у вас ширина/высота RecyclerView = wrapContent или 0 и поэтому метод что выше даже не вызовется. Или даже история с разметкой элемента списка, его просто не видно из-за ширины.

Comment: @woesss, Да именно так, ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Valeriy, У всех параметров стоит значение: match_parent

Comment: @Valeriy, Дебагер не отрабатывает т.к. лист поступающий в него нулевой.

Comment: Ну, в чём проблема, идите по всему списку, где вы используете логи, так же можно начать с начала, где вы его парсите, и т.д. Вы похоже нам показали логи интерсептора (перехватчика), а нужно вам увидеть данные в своих оьектах, распарсенными.

Comment: @Valeriy я так понимаю у меня проблемы с парсингом, потому что после колл объекта ничего не отрабатывает. Но я не понимаю, почему он тогда не укажет, что не может распарсить?

Comment: Добавил модель, может быть поможет

Comment: Если это проблема парсинга - добавьте в `onFailure` распечатку ошибки `t.printStackTrace();` и в логах это увидите.

Comment: @woesss, Распечатало это: com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected an int but was cd at path $.data[0].properties[0].value

Comment: Ну правильно - в `Property` поле `value` должно быть `String`, а у Вас `Integer`.

Comment: @woesss, Благодарю вас все заработало. Это было сложно для меня, так как я новичок)

Comment: @woesss, Возможно ли комментарии отмечать, как правильный ответ?

Comment: комментарий можно только отметить полезным.

Comment: Все когда-то были новичками, вам говорят об очень мощном инструменте: логи и дебагинг. Спасибо создателям этих очень важных вещей, а вы ими пользуйтесь. я открою вам секрет: даже супер профи ими пользуются! Точнее даже так: чем профи отличается от новичка? Профи знает что сразу завернуть в логи и где поставить брекпоинт.